# Visual C++ 2010 -> Window Form. How to convert string to int?

Tags: c++-cli, type-conversion, int32

Hey! I have textBox  with text like "12:30" and this code `textBox -> Text -> ToString() -> Split(':')[1]` It return "30" as string. And I want convert it to Int. How? I founded function like Convert::ToInt32() etc, but it doesnt work for my c++ (Visual C++ 2010 -> Winfow Form). Help me plz! (I started learn c++ 2 days ago)

And i use **Managed** C++

Comment: why doesn't it work? Do you get an error

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on something that is already a string is redundant. The `TextBox.Text` property returns a string. You don't need to use `ToString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using Managed C++, then you can do this:

```
double foo = System::Convert::ToDouble("200");
int bar = System::Convert::ToInt32("200");
```

Use whatever you need!

Comment: If I include `#include<sstream>` after my `using namespace System;`, I get a lot of errors...

Comment: @MegaFill : you should  have tell that you're using Managed C++. Not Visual C++.

Comment: @MegaFill: You *could* do this. If you want to throw an exception if the number you're trying to convert to a string is not actually a number. What if the user typed `AA:BB` into the textbox? **You're actually looking for [`Int32::TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).**

Answer (score 1):

you can use c standard lib frunction atoi

```
CString s = "30";
int x = atoi( s ); // x is now 30
```

Edit: Oh, your are using managed C++, then one of the following two should do the job

```
System::Convert::ToInt32(str, 10);
System::Int32::Parse(str);
```

Refer to this page with an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx

Comment: Sorry, how to do it in Managed C++? ')

Comment: Have people just never heard of `TryParse`? He's using a value from a *textbox*. There's no reason to handle an exception if the user types something that is not a number.

Comment: The last time I was coding for .Net was 3 years ago, things got rusty :)

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
int intVar = Int32::Parse(stringVar);
```